# Does Google Cloud Storage Bucket charges for Bandwidth ?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

I have seen the documentation & pricing calculator but, not getting clear Idea if bucket is charged externally for data transfers / (Bandwidth consumed) or not.

Its showing

```
Storage cost
$0.026 per GB-month

Retrieval cost
Free

Class A operations (Create/ delete )
$0.005 per 1,000 ops

Class B operations (Downloads)
$0.0004 per 1,000 ops
```

Does this retrieval cost means no extra charges will be levied for any amount of data transfer/ bandwidth used for files stored .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "retrieval cost" is a special charge that is specific to nearline and coldline objects. Because these tiers are designed around data being seldomly read, there is a fee to read objects stored under these tiers in addition to any other costs.

Bandwidth consumption, when reading from GCS, is a network usage fee. It's a bit complicated, but basically you're paying for GCS to send the data somewhere. This may be free if you're sending the data to a nearby GCP service, or otherwise the cost will be based on where the data is being stored and where the data is being read from. For example, if the data is being stored in Iowa, it will be more expensive to read it from China than it will be to read it from Oregon.

For more details, see https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing or [contact the sales team](https://cloud.google.com/contact/).

Answer (score 1):

You are charged for bandwidth.

[Retrieval cost](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#archival-pricing) is a separate charge associated with Nearline and Coldline storage.

"A retrieval cost applies when you read data or metadata that is stored as Nearline Storage or Coldline Storage. This cost is in addition to any network charges associated with reading the data."